# how can I return a subclass reference from superclass method

Tags: java, inheritance, builder-pattern

I have a superclass method which returns itself(for builder pattern). This class has several subclasses , so I want to return a reference to actual(subclass) type of the object. Something like this:

```
class SuperClass {
   T someMethodThatDoesSameThingForAllSubclasses() {

    // blablbal
    return reference_of_actual_object;

  }

}
```

So that I can call other subclass methods from subclass reference without casting. Like this:

```
SubClass obj=new SubClass(); 
obj.someMethodThatDoesSameThingForAllSubclasses().someSubclassMethod();
//currently this gives compiler error.  because first method returns superclass reference and super class doesn't have     someSubclassMethod
```

Is this posible and does it make sense to try to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no particularly nice way of doing this, that I'm aware of. The best I've seen is just to cast - which you can do once, of course:

```
public class Superclass<T extends Superclass<T>> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private final T thisAsT = (T) this;

    T someMethodThatDoesSameThingForAllSubclasses() {
       return thisAsT;
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass<Subclass> {
    Subclass subclassOnlyMethod() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Subclass subclass = new Subclass().someMethodThatDoesSameThingForAllSubclasses()
                                  .subclassOnlyMethod();
```

It's horrible that the cast doesn't *actually* check anything due to type erasure, but that's the joy of Java generics :(

Comment: This way I couldn't invoke the subclass method. compile error remains. Plus there also is problem with inner customexception class. this way compiler doesnt let the inheritene from Throwable.

Comment: @user3354638: Well you haven't mentioned exceptions before - but the subclass should be fine, so long as you give it the right `T`. I'll show an example.

Comment: I added caller 'caster' methods to all subclasses. It is horrible but does the job for now.

Comment: @user3354638: But why? The code I've given does the same sort of thing, but in one go. Do you mean you've got an *abstract* `caster` method in the superclass, which you then implement in each subclass? While that removes a *potentially* invalid cast, I don't think it has any practical benefit.

Comment: By the way this is SQL builder class. the superclass is Sql and subclasses are Select,Update etc.. and the method is 'where'. It returns a reference to Sql which makes builder pattern fail.

Comment: @user3354638: Well make it return a reference to `T` instead - as per my code. It sounds like you didn't follow the code in my answer correctly.

Comment: I applied your aprouch but it didn’t  seem to remove the need of casting. this how I call: `new Delete("test").where("id", "7")).run()` .. where method return Sql(super class) and it doesnt have run() method

Comment: Your right. I was extending subclasses without type paremeters. Now, it works. And since type erasure is not that problem in my case this is perfect solution.   Thank you.